# Wrong definition of UINT16_C in arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I noticed that arm-none-eabi-gcc 10.2 defines the macros `UINTN_C` in the following way (compiling with `-mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=c99 -g3 -O0`):

```
#define UINT32_C(x) __UINT32_C(x)  
#define UINT16_C(x) __UINT16_C(x)
```

Then

```
#define __UINT32_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINT16_C(c) c
```

The C99 standard (7.18.4.1 p2) says that:

> The macro UINTN_C(value) shall expand to an unsigned integer constant
> with the specified value and type uint_leastN_t.

The 32 bits version is indeed expanding to an unsigned 32 bits representation (`uint_least32_t` is `unsigned long` on this CPU).

However the 16 bits version expands to a signed representation: `UINT16_C(1)` expands to `1` which is of type `int`.

Isn't it contradictory to the standard ? Is there an option of gcc that would fix that ?

Why not doing something like `#define __UINT16_C(c)  ((uint_least16_t)(c))` ?

Comment: Did you look into the respective header files for some information?

Comment: Yes I did a grep for `__UINTN_C` in the whole directory of my gcc install but didn't find it

Comment: Looks like this is the usual definition in gcc, for example https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/stdint.h.html

Comment: Well, my MinGW installation reveals for example `#define UINT32_C(val) (val##U)`, but I didn't look into details.

Comment: Same here for `UINT32_C`. problem is for 16 and 8 bits

Comment: Doesn't integer promotion get in your way if you cast down an expression and assign it, even to a variable of the type in the cast? (I cannot access the standard right now.)

Comment: @thebusybee well on the contrary my understanding is that the purpose of these macros is to avoid promotion or implicit cast. You cast to 16 bits and assign to a 16 bits variable, everything is explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C doesn't recognize the notion of a numeric literal whose type is smaller than `int` and `unsigned int`.  On a platform where `int` is 32 bits, the expression `(uint16_t)123` would behave as type `signed int` as a result of integer promotion, and it would be somewhat illogical for an expression containing a numeric literal of supposed type `uint16_t` to behave in a manner inconsistent with the way any other expression of that type would be processed.

Comment: I'm surprised that `(uint16_t)123`  would behave as a signed integer. Also what is the point of defining these new macros `UINTN_C` if they are incompatible with the rest of the standards ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: Given something like `(uint32_t)-0x9000, a platform where `int` is 16 bits would yield a value of `0x00007000` rather than `FFFF7000`.  The real problem is that the Committee couldn't decide between adding real fixed-sized numeric types or allowing code that uses new types to be processed using old compilers with the aid of a suitable typedef, and so ends up with a nasty hodgepodge where e.g. multiplication of two `uint16_t` values may trigger nonsensical behavior in some compilers.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: I think the authors of the Standard thought that in most cases where there would be a *defined* difference in behavior between having smaller unsigned types promote to signed, the signed behavior was more logical, and in cases where unsigned arithmetic would have defined behavior but signed arithmetic wouldn't, the only implementations that wouldn't process them identically would be those targeting obscure platforms that couldn't process full-width unsigned math efficiently.  Nonetheless, gcc will sometimes behave nonsensically when multiplying uint16_t values.

Comment: " Given something like (uint32_t)-0x9000, a platform where int` is 16 bits would yield a value of 0x00007000 rather than FFFF7000" Are you sure about that ? the C99 standard says (6.4.4.1) that the type of an integer constant without suffix is the first in a list  in which its value can be represented, the list being: int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, etc... So for me -0x9000 should be of type `long int` on a 16 bits integer machine. then the cast to `uint32_t` should convert to `FFFF7000`

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: The rules are different for hex literals and decimal literals.  Decimal literals without suffixes are never signed, but unsuffixed hex literals which fall between INT_MAX and UINT_MAX are unsigned.  Many of C's type rules wouldn't make sense if one were designing a language from scratch, but were intended to maximize compatibility with code written for a variety of implementations which applied slightly different semantics when they added unsigned types to the language.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: Note that when C was designed, no integral types could hold values outside the range of `int`, which was the type used for all integer computations, so there was never any ambiguity about how things should promote.  When implementations added unsigned types, the semantics of those types weren't always the same.  Rather than add any new types whose semantics would be the same on all implementations, the Standard instead tried to write rules that would be consistent with what implementations were already doing.

Comment: "Decimal literals without suffixes are never signed" I think you meant always signed according to 6.4.4.1.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: I meant never unsigned, since signed was initially the only kind of number and remained the default.